# Map Image type property using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class with a property of type `System.Drawing.Image` because I want to store images in it. When trying to scaffold a Web API controller with Entity Framework Core I get the error message:

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7aPZ.png)

I think the problem is that the `System.Drawing.Image` class has a "Tag" property of type `object`. Now, the question is how do I fix this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**:

Instead of using `System.Drawing.Image` directly in EF mapping, you could map the data to another property of type `byte[]`

```
[NotMapped]
public System.Drawing.Image Image { get; set; }

public byte[] ImageData 
{
    get 
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Image.Save(ms, Image.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    set  
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            Image = null;
        }
        else
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(value))
            {
                Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**:

You could also leave only the `ImageData` property in the model and handle loading and saving the image outside the model.

```
public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
```